# Automatically resolve git conflicts except for some files

Tags: git

I have the following git repo:

```
oooooooooooooo
   o       o
    o V1    o V2
     o
      o MyChange
```

I have a `git diff` for `V1..MyChange` . Now I would like to merge everything up to `V2` and create a new diff for `V2..MyChange`.

How can I tell Git to auto resolve all conflicts by taking `V2` except for the files present in `V1..MyChange` diff?

I have tried

```
git checkout MyChange
git merge V2
```

and I'm getting 100s of conflicts with both file modifications and file deletions. I just want to take everything from `V2` except for the files I'm interested in `MyChange`.

Comment: Seems like easier (and probably also more correct) to achieve this with `cherry-pick`, applying patches or using `rebase`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a couple patches that are currently applied on top of `V1`, and you want to update your repo and apply your patches on top of `V2`. As mentioned in [@Yehezkel's comment](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39705946/automatically-resolve-git-conflicts-except-for-some-files#comment66710185_39705946), `rebase` is a better way to do this.

Specifically, you can do:

```
git checkout MyChange
git rebase --onto V2 V1
```

Or simply:

```
git rebase --onto V2 V1 MyChange
```

This will cause your history to look like this:

```
oooooooooooooo
   o       o
    o V1    o V2
             o
              o MyChange
```

You may still have conflicts, but it should be limited to *actual* conflicts, i.e. files that have changed both in `V2` and in your patches.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this. I didn't use `--onto` before, which lead to many conflicts, so the rebasing was aborting all the time, telling me to fix the conflicts first.

Comment: I've tried this now, the rebase is halting at every single commit due to conflicts. Not sure how to address this, feels like I'm redoing the whole feature development work manually.

Comment: @siamii Are these actual conflicts (things that you have changed in `MyChange` that were also changed in `V2`)? Or do you have to keep redoing already-completed conflict resolutions? If the latter, then [`git rerere`](//stackoverflow.com/a/7241744/2747593) could be helpful.