# Sync specific changes from a cloned repo using Git?

Tags: git, github, synchronization, clone

I have cloned a repository from github using the `git clone` command.

I have made changes to this repository e.g. editing and deleting files + adding my own files etc.

During this time, changes have been made to the original repository (from which I cloned) e.g. the owner of that repo has updated build files etc.

It would be beneficial to include these changes in my project.

However, I don't want to have to do this manually if possible.

Using Git, is there any way to merge only the *specific* changes to the github repo that I want to include in my project - (since merging the whole project would re-include files from the original that I may have since deleted).

Comment: Looks to be duplicate question see [how to merge specific files in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979201/how-to-merge-specific-files-in-git)

Comment: @Samundra thanks for the link but im not sure it entirely answers the question. do you know the exact process for performing this operation between a github repo and a local repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically resolve git conflicts except for some files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705946/automatically-resolve-git-conflicts-except-for-some-files)

Comment: Just merge it normally with `git pull` and it *will not* re-include files you've already removed from the repository.